# Jquery find the closest div class and grab its ID

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve the id of the closest div tag with a specific class.

I currently have

```
var del = $(this).closest(".column").attr("id");
          console.log(del);
```

I only seem to receive back Undefined

I have also tried using `parent()` and this returns the same result

Below is the full code used

```js
$(".portlet")
  .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
  .find(".portlet-header")
  .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
  .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'>-</span><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-delete'>X</span>");


$(".portlet-toggle").click(function() {
  var icon = $(this);
  icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
  icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});




$(".column").on("click", ".portlet-delete", function() {
  $(this).closest('div.portlet').remove();
  var del = $(this).closest(".column").attr("id");
  console.log(del);


});
```

```html
<div class="column" id="left">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_1>">
    <div class="portlet-header">Header</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Content</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column" id="middle">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_2>">
    <div class="portlet-header">Header</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Content</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column" id="right">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_3>">
    <div class="portlet-header">Header</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is $(this) in this case? HTML sample would be great....

Comment: Can you share your html or add a fiddler?

Comment: Added some more information. Thanks

Comment: Can you fix your stack snippet so that `.portlet-toggle` and `.portlet-delete` have some text in them so we can click on them?

Comment: Few problems - dynamic creation of spans, event propagation... you should separate clicks on column and on span... Please setup fiddle with full CSS, if possible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting `undefined` is because you're trying to find the closest `.column` after you remove the containing `div.portlet`. So `this` is no longer in the DOM, and there's no closest `.column` any more.

Switch the order of those two lines and it should work.

```js
$(".portlet")
  .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
  .find(".portlet-header")
  .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
  .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'> Toggle </span><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-delete'> Del </span>");

$(".portlet-toggle").click(function() {
  var icon = $(this);
  icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
  icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});

$(".column").on("click", ".portlet-delete", function() {
  var del = $(this).closest(".column").attr("id");
  console.log(del);
  $(this).closest('div.portlet').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column" id="left">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_1>">
    <div class="portlet-header">Header 1</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Content 1</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column" id="middle">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_2>">
    <div class="portlet-header">Header 2</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Content 2</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column" id="right">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_3>">
    <div class="portlet-header">Header 3</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Content 3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh of course it is seems so simple now thinking about it. I have tried this and it appears to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that 'this' is not inside of '.column' so the function cant find a matching element. An other problem could be that '.column' has no id attr.

```
<div class="column" id="test"><div class="inner"></div></div>

var del = $('.inner').closest(".column").attr("id");
console.log(del); // => test
```

Comment: Why do you think this isn't inside `.column`? The first block of code prepends `.portlet-toggle` and `.portlet-delete` to `$(".portlet").find(".portlet-header")`, and all the `.portlet` are inside `.column`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Leer6y6o/

You have to make sure that the item you are trying to find the closest to is wrapping the element which is invoking.

```
<div class="column" id="test">
<button>
    Test
</button>
    </div>

$("button").click(function()
{
   var d = $(this).closest(".column").attr("id");
      alert(d);
});
```